# Modify expressions, generated by Antlr?

Tags: java, antlr, antlr4

I would like to read expressions with Antlr4 and the perform some modifications on them.

For example, if grammar is arithmetic, I would modify expression, representing

```
2 * (3 + 1)
```

with

```
2 * 4
```

and then with

```
8
```

This is "calculation" or "simplification". To perform this thing I would create some tree structure and the first idea is to use the very same trees, created by Antlr.

Unfortunately, I don't see any setters for children.

How to accomplish? Should I really duplicate Antlr trees with my own ones for logic of expressions?

Comment: http://www.antlr.org/api/Java/org/antlr/v4/runtime/TokenStreamRewriter.html

Comment: Why does appending occur in text form? I need to modify tree, i.e. create and delete nodes. These modified nodes can be text free.

Answer (score 11):

### Solution

You shouldn't duplicate nor modify ANTRL trees. You should **USE** them by utilizing tree visitor and listener patterns.

#### The grammar

First we will prepare simple grammar for an arithmetic expression.

```
grammar expr;

WS : [ \t\r\n] -> skip;
INT : [0-9]+;

program
    : expr # baseExpr
    ;

expr
    : '(' expr ')'              # exprParentheses
    | left=expr '*' right=expr  # exprMul
    | left=expr '+' right=expr  # exprAdd
    | INT                       # exprINT
    ;
```

#### Evaluate expression

In order to evaluate an expression, we will traverse the parse tree to perform a calculation or to collect the result.

```
public class EvaluateExpr extends exprBaseVisitor<Integer> {
    @Override
    public Integer visitExprINT(exprParser.ExprINTContext ctx) {
        return Integer.valueOf(ctx.INT().getText());
    }

    @Override
    public Integer visitExprMul(exprParser.ExprMulContext ctx) {
        Integer left = visit(ctx.left);
        Integer right = visit(ctx.right);
        return left * right;
    }

    @Override
    public Integer visitExprAdd(exprParser.ExprAddContext ctx) {
        Integer left = visit(ctx.left);
        Integer right = visit(ctx.right);
        return left + right;
    }

    @Override
    public Integer visitExprParentheses(exprParser.ExprParenthesesContext ctx) {
        return visit(ctx.expr());
    }
}
```

#### Replace expression

In order to replace an expression with its evaluated form, we will use `TokenStreamRewriter` class. This tool allows for an easy substitution of tokens.

```
public class ReplaceExpr extends exprBaseListener {
    private TokenStreamRewriter rewriter;

    public ReplaceExpr(CommonTokenStream tokens) {
        rewriter = new TokenStreamRewriter(tokens);
    }

    @Override
    public void enterBaseExpr(exprParser.BaseExprContext ctx) {
        rewriter.replace(ctx.start, ctx.stop, new EvaluateExpr().visit(ctx));
    }

    public String getReplacedCode() {
        return rewriter.getText();
    }
}
```

#### Run the example

Now we need to perform evaluation and replacement of the expressions.

```
exprLexer lexer = new exprLexer(new ANTLRInputStream("2 * (3 + 1)"));
CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
exprParser parser = new exprParser(tokens);
ReplaceExpr replaceExpr = new ReplaceExpr(tokens);
ParseTreeWalker.DEFAULT.walk(replaceExpr, parser.program());
System.out.println("Replaced code: " + replaceExpr.getReplacedCode());
```

#### The parse tree or AST (abstract-syntax tree)

If you still need a modified parse tree you can parse the altered code again.
If you would like to modify the tree structure, convert the parse tree to the [AST](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Abstract_syntax_tree) (abstract-syntax tree), and work on the [AST](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Abstract_syntax_tree) from the start.